# Align the CollectionView cells with Autolayout for all devices

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a problem with constraint on xCode 9.
I have an UIVIewController with a UIView that contains an UICollectionView that shows the days of the current month, everything works perfection but I have problems with the cells on the various devices ...

**The collectionView uses paging for cell scrolling**

---

Here you see that on iPhone 8 plus it's ok but on iPhone If the cells are cut ..
[image]

I set UICollectionViewFlowLayout for my collectionView but still has problems ... Probably might be the wrong constraint but i can not understand which of these constraints is wrong.

---

***Here is the image of the constraint I used for the Custom Cell***
[image]

---

***Here are the constraints of the Custom UIView I have placed in the UIViewController***

[image]

---

***I also show you the code I used, maybe the mistake is here***

```
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder: aDecoder];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setupContent:(UIView *)controller {

    _arrayWeek = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _arrayDay = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *smartLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _smartCalendar = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds collectionViewLayout:smartLayout];

    //////// Collection View ////////
    _smartCalendar.delegate = self;
    _smartCalendar.dataSource = self;
    _smartCalendar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _smartCalendar.pagingEnabled = YES;

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"UDSmartCalendarCell" bundle: nil];
    [_smartCalendar registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellID];

    _smartCalendar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self addSubview:_smartCalendar];

     //////// CONSTRAINT COLLECTION VIEW ////////
    [_smartCalendar.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.trailingAnchor constant:0.0].active = YES;
    [_smartCalendar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
    [_smartCalendar.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.widthAnchor].active = YES;
    [_smartCalendar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:60].active = YES;

     //////// FLOW LAYOUT COLLECTION VIEW////////
    smartLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    CGFloat width = floorf(_smartCalendar.frame.size.width  / 6);
    smartLayout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width, 50);
    smartLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3;
    smartLayout.minimumLineSpacing =3;
    smartLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    _smartCalendar.collectionViewLayout = smartLayout;
    _smartCalendar.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;


    [self buildSmartCalendarWithWeekArray:_arrayWeek andDay:_arrayDay];
    [self scrollToItemToday];

}
```